# Criteria nested associations in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, criteria

I'm creating a query using Criteria on my Grails project, and I have to access a property in a nested association.

I'm creating the query using **createCriteria** and **.list** function on my **PaymentRecord** model, where I have this association:

```
Area area
static belongsTo = [area: Area]
```

And I need to access the property **areaCode** inside the referred area, this is my last approach but still not working:

```
def areas = params."chartsForm[areas][]"
                    if (areas instanceof String) {
                        'area'{
                            eq("area.areaCode", "$areas")
                        }
                    }
```

Any idea or mistake I'm not seeing?

Comment: Not related to your question but in your `PaymentRecord` class you probably don't need to declare the `Area area` property.  GORM should be adding that property to your class as a result of  `static belongsTo = [area: Area]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
def results = PaymentRecord.withCriteria {
    if(areas instanceof String) {
      area {
          eq 'areaCode', areas
      }
    }
}
```